# Heap space issue with hadoop-streaming using Hadoop 2x

Tags: hadoop, heap-memory, hadoop-streaming

I am having a serious issue with Hadoop 2.4. I am trying to run my use case which is a groovy script using hadoop-streaming jar. It results in error: `Java heap space - No memory`.

Here is my configuration:

yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>master:8025</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>master:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>master:8040</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>128</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>6144</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>4</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
    <value>2.1</value>
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx2048m</value>
</property>
```

I have 8 GB RAM on every node and there is no reduce task.

My command line to run the job is as follows:-

> $HADOOP_INSTALL/bin/hadoop jar
>   $HADOOP_INSTALL/hadoop-streaming-2.4.0.jar -libjars ${LIBJARS} -input
>   /input.txt -mapper "Launcher.groovy ${args}" -inputformat
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.NLineInputFormat -output /${dir}

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong? I did not have any such issue with hadoop 1.2.1.